# CPU/Mem usage for cron jobs on GCP K8S while not running

Tags: cron, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I have setup a cron job on GCP Kubernetes. It runs once per day at 10:00am.
The job runs as expected however, I don't really understand what the charts say on the GCP K8S console.

[image]

As shown in the charts, there are around 1.5 CPU and 8G RAM at this point, when the cron job is not running. I expect the current usage should be zero as it is **not** running.

Could anyone see what is wrong? or I read the charts wrong?

Note I do retain 7 jobs in the history. Each job ran about 15sec and completed successfully.

```
State:          Terminated
  Reason:       Completed
  Exit Code:    0
  Started:      Thu, 08 Mar 2018 04:00:56 +0000
  Finished:     Thu, 08 Mar 2018 04:01:09 +0000
```

[image]

20180320 EDIT:
I found all graphs from other cron jobs all look the same. Is it something I setup wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you cron job executes ? Is it a short action that executes and end quickly or is it a long process that runs throughout a long period of time ?

Comment: From the log, each job ran less than 15 sec, so they are pretty quick. It basically scans through the database and sends a reminder to our users whose accounts are expiring.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your situation by that way:

1. Created CronJob with a name "Application"
2. Added an application using Deployment with a name "Application"

And now, I see on graphics of Cron Job details information not only about a cronjob itself, but also about an application.

So, I think, dashboard using **name of object** for getting a data.

Looks like you have any other deployment, replicaset etc. which always running and has a same name as your cronjob and on graphics you see the mix of data from it and from your cronjob.

Comment: The problem might be similar. I don't have any deployment or resource with similar names to this cron job. Digging more, I found all the cron jobs share the same graph. Maybe I setup wrong?